# Reducing ImpredicativeTypes to RankNTypes with CPS

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, ghc

Which of these four statements is false?

- `newtype` and `data` definitions could be replaced by `type` constructions of `(->)` and `forall`.
- `RankNTypes` is implemented correctly.
- `ImpredicativeTypes` would be hard to implement correctly even if GADTs didn't exist.
- The first two statements refute the third.

---

Edit: I'm surprised that wasn't clear. `data Maybe = Nothing | Just a` could be written as `type Maybe a = forall b. b -> (a -> b) -> b`. `data [] a = [] | a : [a]` could be written as `type [] a = forall b. b -> (a -> b -> b) -> b`. (Compare to `maybe` and `foldr`.) The same thing ought to be possible for all `newtype` and `data` definitions, and is called continuation passing style (CPS).

As far as I know, type inference for types that have deeply nested `forall`s and `(->)` is implemented correctly by `ghc` using the `RankNTypes` extension, but `ImpredicativeTypes`, which allows `forall`s even in arguments to type constructors other than `(->)`, is hopelessly broken.

But couldn't you implement `ImpredicativeTypes` by translating all `data` and `newtype` types to their CPS forms, using `RankNTypes` machinery for inference and then translating back into `data`/`newtype` forms?

Comment: It would probably be worth it expanding a little on statement #4.

Comment: Uhm... where are these statements taken from? It's hard if not impossible to answer these without proper context.

Comment: "ImpredicativeTypes would be hard to implement correctly" ... ImpredicativeTypes is not implemented correctly now, nor has it ever been.

Comment: I think I heard that RankN full type inference is undecidable (Rank2 already is, IIRC, but I have no references to cite). GHC implements RankN but relies on the user to annotate every polytyped variable with its polytype. It's not fully automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of them. The difficulty in using `ImpredicativeTypes` comes from not having type inference, requiring the user to provide explicit type signatures. You assume that since `RankNTypes` are widely used that type inference works in general for `RankNTypes`, but that's [not true](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/RankNTypes):

> It is not possible to infer higher-rank types in general; type annotations must be supplied by the programmer in many cases.

Comment: (If you see "includes complete type conference" as contained in "correct", then 2 is false. If not, 3 is false.)